# fluent nhibernate encoding settings

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

how can i set the encoding when i'm configure nhibernate with fluent configuration on mysql

my problem is that i'm saving hebrew text on db and all i see in my app is ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not related to Fluent NHibernate. When you [create](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html) your database you indicate the encoding:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Also verify that you append `;charSet=utf8` to your connection string.

Comment: i create the db through nhibernate...
and i tried to add this char set and nothing works..

Comment: Once the database is created can you verify the collation that is applied with the tool you use to administer your mySQL server (probably `mysqladmin`).